# tfs: Each environment state will change between "Ready" and "Not Ready" alternately for in minutes

Tags: tfs

Today we find that tfs lab center Environment is not stable.
Each environment state will change between "Ready" and "Not Ready" alternately for in minutes.

We have tested:
 1. Network from TFS to scvmm server is ok
 2. Network from test controller to lab center host is ok

There are some errors in Lab center:

> Environment message: Type=Error; Message=TF259633: Team Foundation
>   Server has detected that the following test controller is offline:
>   [Test Controller VM Name]. Either bring the controller back
>   online, or update the environment and use a different test
>   controller.;
>
> Machine messages:
>
> Machine name: [Environment VM Name]
>
> Machine message: Type=Error; Message=Unable to connect to the
>   controller on '[Test Controller VM Name]'. Reason: An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>   [Test Controller IP]. Make sure the test controller is online and reachable from this machine. Ensure that the firewall on the test
>   controller is not blocking the connection.;

There are some errors on build controller vm:

> (QTController.exe, PID 808, Thread 21) ControllerConfiguration: Agent
>   'vstfs:///LabManagement/TestMachine/190' attempted to connect but
>   failed: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Exceptions.EqtException: The
>   agent can connect to the controller but the controller cannot connect
>   to the agent because of following reason: The read operation failed,
>   see inner exception. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.AgentMachine.VerifyAgentConnection(Int32
>   timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerConfiguration.ConnectAgent(String
>   agentName, String machineName, Boolean canPerformUITesting, String
>   configuredUserName, String agentVersion, IAgentService agentService,
>   WindowsIdentity remoteIdentity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have checked the error is caused by that test controller have not been reconfigured after test controller machine re-configured.

Out test controller and build controller are installed on one machine.

Yesterday, in order to fix the [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991771/tfs-a-service-host-may-only-be-active-on-one-machine-at-a-time-type-buildserv/24992407#24992407), we need to reconfigure our build controller and its related build agent.

But when all work done, we forget to re-configure test controller.

After reconfigure test controller, the issue is fixed.