# Visual Studio 2013 + TFS = Slow

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am using a recently re-installed laptop with SSD. I am using Visual Studio 2013 with TFS.

My problem is that I need to wait for about 20 - 25 seconds when I'm starting and when I'm ending a merge or compare. The waiting time for ending a web debug session is also about 30 seconds.

I have no special configuration. The TFS server is in our LAN and I'm connected via ethernet. I do not have a proxy configured in TFS settings.

I already tried the following:

- Deleted suo files
- Added setting to visual studio 2013 app config to disable proxy.
- Storing symbols locally
- Re-added mappings
- Re-added workspace

I'm not have this problems with projects that are outside TFS. My colleagues are not having this problem.

Comment: Which version of TFS? What is your workspace configuration (Local or Server)? Is is also slow when you are working offline? What's the number of files in your workspace?

Comment: We are using TFS 2013. The workspace is rather big (about 40k files and the size is about 6.2gb). I already tried a smaller workspace with no improvements

Comment: Local or Server workspace?

Comment: I tried both, with the same results.

Comment: Was it ever faster before you installed the SSD?

Comment: Well. Things like building are much faster. It seems that there only are problems with compare/merge and stopping web app debug sessions. I kinda had this problems before without my SSD, but when I reinstalled VS the problems were gone. Yesterday I tried to do a compare. This took 25 seconds. My colleague only needed 1 - 2 seconds for the same action on a much older and slower laptop. It seems to me that it has to do with something of a network timeout. But I will enable VS and TFS and maybe I can find it.

Comment: My guts say: check the IP routes and DNS settings.

Answer (score 54):

There are a number of options available to you which you haven't tried yet:

### Local workspace vs Server Workspace

When you have a large workspace (meaning lots of files in your workspace) or when your workspace contains a lot of binary files (NuGet Packages for example), it may slow down considerably when it's configured as a "Local Workspace". Local workspaces keep the original file (latest version as your TFS server knows it) in a gzipped file on disk. Whenever a lot of files change, they're compared against the last known copy and based on that they're either checked in or checked out.

A Server workspace on the other hand simply looks at the 'read-only' bit of the files. If it has one, TFS will assume it's unchanged. If it doesn't have one, TFS assumes it's checked out.

Local workspaces have their advantages, especially if you work offline a lot, but they can cause serious slowdown in the cases described above.

Try configuring your workspace as a Server workspace to see if that removes the issue.

[image]

Visual Studio, by default, creates a Local workspace ever since this feature was introduced.

### Remove large binary files, and scope the workspace appropriately

If you want to use a Local workspace, you may need to update your solution to ensure that NuGet packages are not checked in, large binary files in your workspace are cloaked and that you only grab the files you really need (e.g. create a new workspace for different branches).

To cloak a file, either edit your workspace mapping and add a folder you do not want to retrieve and set the action from "active" to "cloak", or you can cloak directly from the context menu of the Source Control Explorer, you can find it under <kbd>Advanced</kbd> then <kbd>Cloak</kbd>.

Instead of checking in your binary references, try to find corresponding NuGet packages, or create them yourself. Large binary files are always a pest when it comes to Version Control Systems, as you can never merge them and they basically just sit there.

### Cache corruption

The Team Explorer client keeps a cache in the following location:

> C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation{version}\Cache

Which may have become corrupted for some reason. Clearing all sub-folders and the `VersionControl.config` can be a last resort to get it working again.

### Repair Visual Studio and turn off extensions

Sometimes Visual Studio itself can be a little confused by all the hotfixes, service packs and other things that get installed. To not even mention all the extensions that may influence it's behavior.

Some extensions can seriously slow down interactions with source control. The before mentioned Source Control Explorer Extensions, for example have an option to change the date of the files on disk, which can cause "Get" operations to stall at the very end for a number of seconds.

Turning off such extensions to see if the behavior still exists without them is always something you should do. Repairing Visual Studio and re-applying the latest update pack is also something that may resolve issues like these.

Suspect extensions include those that:

- Extend the Debugger
- Extend Team Explorer
- Extend the Source Control Explorer

### Turn off Windows Proxy auto-detection

I've seen some strage behavior, not on all networks, not with all proxy servers, when Windows Proxy Auto Detection is turned on. Proxy detection can cause long waits as it's trying to figure out what proxy to connect to.

Try disabling the proxy script and auto-detection, if you're dependent on a proxy, try setting it directly in the classic proxy configuration screen:

[image]

### Try to find the issue the hard way

Enable [client side tracing as described here](http://www.markrainey.me/2014/11/setting-up-client-trace-with-tfs-2013.html). In the `devenv.exe.config` include the following snippet. It will dump everything that happens around TFS to a log file. It can be a pain to pinpoint what's happening, but it will give you loads of information:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
    <add name="TeamFoundationSoapProxy" value="4" />
    <add name="VersionControl" value="4" />
  </switches>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="3">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" type="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationTextWriterTraceListener,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" initializeData="c:\tf.log" />
      <add name="perfListener" type="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PerfTraceListener,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And you can run Visual Studio with Activity Trace Logging enabled. If there's a plugin misbehaving it often results in information in the `ActivityLog.xml`. To enable this type of traces, start visual studio with the `/log` option from the commandline. The log will be dropped here:

> %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.XML

In the worst case you can attach one Visual studio or a profiler (or the Intellitrace commandline tool) to Visual Studio and collect a log of everythign that happens inside Visual Studio.

And you could try monitoring your system with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see if IO or network access are slowing you down.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to scale down my workspace, removed the cache and tried to transform to server workspace. This did not help. I will now try a repair and disabling extensions.

Comment: I tried the repair and disabling of extensions. This did not help. I will try to enable the logging and see what's happening. Thanks.

Comment: Logging is always takes time...still waiting for your results:)

Comment: Thank you very much, this post saved my day!

Comment: I was experiencing extreme slowness with TFS. For example: expanding a folder or a branch would take 20-30 seconds. Switching to a server workspace made it lightning fast.

Comment: You are a life saver. I've been struggling with TFS performance for months. I must have fallen victim to the "Upgrade" to a local workspace message. Thank you!

Comment: Very comprehensive answer thanks Jesse.  I reverted to a server workspace but I don't like that the local workspace solution was / is so slow.  I've contacted the product team on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with Win10 64bit. VS2015-TFS etc. I resolved it by changing the laptops power plan from 'Power saver' to 'High performance' ...

Answer (score -2):

The problem with TFS is that it completely integrates with your IDE.

I suggest using GIT. You can convert your project from tfs to git using various tools for example git-tfs, see https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md

There is also a blog post about one who does this:
https://chriskirby.net/blog/migrate-an-existing-project-from-tfs-to-github-with-changeset-history-intact

Comment: Visual Studio also integrates Git directly in the IDE. And if you wanted you could turn of TFS integration in the IDE and perform all actions from the commandline using `tf.exe`.