# TFS 2015 Intermittent connection issues

Tags: tfs

For the last few weeks our office has experienced intermittent and fairly crippling connection issues to our on premises TFS 2015 (w/update3). When it occurs visual studio basically becomes useless and web view pages of TFS either don't load the page, load the header toolbars or take several minutes and eventually open. Queries take minutes to run and so on. Then suddenly all will be well and it works again perfectly.

There are no errors shown when this happens, either to the user or in the TFS application event logs. The system is not overloaded on any resources. I have tried various things like; rebooting (obviously!), iisrest, cleared cache on app tier and who knows what else at this point.

Are there any other logs I could be looking at or things I could try to diagnose?

Worth noting: Users have all recently migrated to a new domain but the TFS servers are still on the old domain. However we had migrated in my office long before these issues occurred. Other offices who connect in have only recently migrated into new domain.

System setup is VMware 6.0, TFS app tier with separate SQL data tier and analysis database.

Comment: This is an issue that's not really feasible to troubleshoot in a Q&A format. Talk to your networking/operations team to rule out network-related issues. If TFS is functional but slow, that's the most likely culprit.

Comment: Hi CK89, any update on this issue, have you figure it out?

Comment: It is still on going. I thought we had resolved it after a week free of issues by removing a resource hungry anti virus module. But it has since reared its head a few times this week again. :(

Comment: @CK89 Have you double checked the network connection in your environment. Suggest you use some tools to do network trace during the TFS Intermittent connection issues. This will help you to narrow down if the issue is related to network or TFS side. Besides, also try to shut down antivirus software temporarily and see if the issue could reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description: *There are no errors shown when this happens, either to the user or in the TFS application event logs.*

Agree with *Daniel* in the comment, this kind of issue should not related to TFS server side. If the server always be slowly, this should be a performance issue. However, you said suddenly all will be well and it works again perfectly. Then the most possibility should be network related issue. Suggest your team use some Network Analyzer Tools to trouble shoot it.

For example,  double check the DNS related area. Your TFS server is on one domain and some users are on another. First make sure the domains are trusted each other, double check that if the slow performance was being caused by an authentication issue.

One of the fix is to have users log in using the full domain name. A sample: if they are currently logging in with DEV\MyUserAccount, then they should instead log in with DEV.COM\MyUserAccount.

It has something to so with how the TFS server is looking up the accounts when a short domain name is used. It is pre-pending the name to all of the dns suffixes which in turn ends up creating bad ones and causes delays as it's not finding any valid domains.

Besides, about the performance issue, you could also take a look at this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28023653/5391065) from *jessehouwing*.